# Why is my cron not running as intended?

Tags: 7, cron

`crontab -e` displays

```
*/5 * * * * /persistent/sitename/scripts/cron-curl.sh
~
~
~
"/tmp/crontab.XXXX1FOZWa" 1L, 51C
```

Why is it not running every 5 minutes?

Comment: To which Drupal version are you interested? There is a little difference with Drupal 7 that you need to take in consideration.

Comment: Drupal 5. Managed to solve the problem with the help of Brock Boland.

Comment: Thank you; I added the tag. If you resolved your own issue, then post an answer where you explain what you did, and accept it as answer. That would help other users with the same issue, and it will help _Drupal Answers_, which needs accepted answers.

Comment: @kiamlaluno without going into too much details, the url in cron-curl.sh must be the same url as the server. In our case, I was using a test server which has a different url to our site's url. This resulted in cron not running.

Comment: That is what Brock Boland was suggesting, then. Remember to accept his answer; without accepted answers, _Drupal Answers_ (this Q&A site) cannot pass the beta phase.

Answer (score 2):

Did you modify `cron-curl.sh` to use the URL for your site? By default, it tries to load http://example.com/cron.php.

Comment: Hi Brock, 
curl --silent --compressed http://www.edocr.com/cron.php

Comment: The formatting got messed up there, but is your site at http://www.edocr.com? The other ones appear to be commented out.

Comment: ah...long story short.. edocr.com is my site, but we have few problems due to recent AWS EC2 outage and I need to replace the url with AWS server name - let me try and get back to you quickly